# World's most simple Windows driver

Tags: windows, windows-xp, device-driver

I have a slightly odd problem involving a MoGo mouse failing to charge when put in the cartridge slot of my Windows XP laptop.  Long story, but one suggestion to fix it is to write a bespoke driver which only says "I'm functioning OK: don't turn the power off".

I'm figuring that this should be next to trivial, but my only experience of drivers is to download and install them through provided MSIs.  I realised that I don't know:

- What language they're written in.
- What conventions they must follow.
- How they are associated with their respective hardware.
- Where they are located.
- Or indeed, anything at all...

I also haven't found anything staggeringly helpful on the web - probably because they are aimed at a far higher level than I'm at.

Any insights would be welcome.

Comment: Since there's no answer yet (but I'm sure a good one will follow ...), have a look at the [Windows Driver Kit (WDK)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/gg487428.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, Gene.  It looks like I might have to jump in with both feet and try to make sense of the Microsoft documentation!

Comment: I've always been curious about this too. Luckily for us, [there is a guide from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/gettingstarted/writing-your-first-driver). Unfortunately this sort of question is off topic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft provides a "Hello World" driver example in their documentation. This is an example of "World's most simple Windows driver". Unfortunately, it's 13 pages long and thus not a good fit for a StackOverflow answer.

The language they are written in is C++.

> To get started, be sure you have Microsoft Visual Studio, the Windows
> SDK, and the Windows Driver Kit (WDK) installed.

Their example contains one file called `Driver.c` that looks like this:

```c++
#include <ntddk.h>
#include <wdf.h>
DRIVER_INITIALIZE DriverEntry;
EVT_WDF_DRIVER_DEVICE_ADD KmdfHelloWorldEvtDeviceAdd;

NTSTATUS 
DriverEntry(
    _In_ PDRIVER_OBJECT     DriverObject, 
    _In_ PUNICODE_STRING    RegistryPath
)
{
    // NTSTATUS variable to record success or failure
    NTSTATUS status = STATUS_SUCCESS;

    // Allocate the driver configuration object
    WDF_DRIVER_CONFIG config;

    // Print "Hello World" for DriverEntry
    KdPrintEx(( DPFLTR_IHVDRIVER_ID, DPFLTR_INFO_LEVEL, "KmdfHelloWorld: DriverEntry\n" ));

    // Initialize the driver configuration object to register the
    // entry point for the EvtDeviceAdd callback, KmdfHelloWorldEvtDeviceAdd
    WDF_DRIVER_CONFIG_INIT(&config, 
                           KmdfHelloWorldEvtDeviceAdd
                           );

    // Finally, create the driver object
    status = WdfDriverCreate(DriverObject, 
                             RegistryPath, 
                             WDF_NO_OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES, 
                             &config, 
                             WDF_NO_HANDLE
                             );
    return status;
}

NTSTATUS 
KmdfHelloWorldEvtDeviceAdd(
    _In_    WDFDRIVER       Driver, 
    _Inout_ PWDFDEVICE_INIT DeviceInit
)
{
    // We're not using the driver object,
    // so we need to mark it as unreferenced
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(Driver);

    NTSTATUS status;

    // Allocate the device object
    WDFDEVICE hDevice;    

    // Print "Hello World"
    KdPrintEx(( DPFLTR_IHVDRIVER_ID, DPFLTR_INFO_LEVEL, "KmdfHelloWorld: KmdfHelloWorldEvtDeviceAdd\n" ));

    // Create the device object
    status = WdfDeviceCreate(&DeviceInit, 
                             WDF_NO_OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES,
                             &hDevice
                             );
    return status;
}
```

Full details found here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/gettingstarted/writing-a-very-small-kmdf--driver

Comment: Thanks @HackSlash.  I don't have that mouse any more, but I'm sure that this will be useful at a later date.